# Array of undefined: reacts

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm just a beginner in react when I try to run my code I get this error, please tell me how and where to fix the error. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        array: [''],
        url:"",

    };

}


search() {
    var path = this.refs.searchbar.value
    this.setState({url: path})
    var newArray = this.state.array;
    newArray.push(path);
    this.setState(array:newArray);
    newArray.map((i)=>{
        console.log(i);
    });

}
```

Error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/searchfield.js
  Line 24:  'array' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: `this.setState(array:newArray);` is a syntax error. You probably meant to put it in a set of braces. Eg: `this.setState({array:newArray});`

Comment: how come I forgot it.  thanks mate @CRice,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that I would like to point out:

1. Always pass the constructor argument to the super constructor.
2. Since you're referencing the same array in `newArray`, you are actually mutating `this.state.array` when you push the `url` to it. This should be avoided; copy the array first before pushing the value and updating the state.
3. There is a syntax error when you set the new array state (this is causing your error).

These things are fixed below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        array: [''],
        url: ""
    };
}

search() {
    var path = this.refs.searchbar.value
    this.setState({url: path})
    var newArray = this.state.array.splice();
    newArray.push(path);
    this.setState({array: newArray});
    newArray.map((i)=>{
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, being new to react I'm also new to javascript. I have heard that you can't copy something in javascript but I guess is wrong. please if know tell me how to copy it and not mutate it, and what would be the difference between them.Your help will really appreciated